# Select a valid choice. 2 is not one of the available choices. Python Django

Tags: python, django

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. При отправке формы вылетает ошибка валидации: *''Select a valid choice. 2 is not one of the available choices''*. И так при каждом варианте выбора.

forms.py

```
class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = ('advertise', 'text', 'mark')
```

models.py

```
class Feedback(models.Model):

    STATUS_FEEDBACK = (
        (1, 'Очень плохо'),
        (2, 'Плохо'),
        (3, 'Терпимо'),
        (4, 'Нормально'),
        (5, 'Отлично'),
    )

    sender = models.ForeignKey('UserAvito', verbose_name='Отправитель', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    advertise = models.ForeignKey('advertisements.Advertise', verbose_name='Объявление', related_name='feedbacks', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    getter = models.ForeignKey('UserAvito', verbose_name='Получатель', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='feedbacks_getter')
    mark = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_FEEDBACK, verbose_name='Оценка', max_length=400)
    date_add = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.sender.username} | {self.advertise.title}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Отзыв'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Отзывы'
```

views.py

```
class FeedbackCreateView(CartMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = FeedbackForm()
        form.advertise = Advertise.objects.filter(seller_id=kwargs.get('pk'))
        return render(request, 'profiles/feedback_create.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = FeedbackForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_feedback = form.save(commit=False)
            new_feedback.sender = request.user
            new_feedback.getter = UserAvito.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('pk'))
            new_feedback.save()
            if new_feedback:
                request.user.feedbacks.add(new_feedback)
            return redirect('profile_user', pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
        return render(request, 'profiles/feedback_create.html', {'form': form})
```

HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="post" action="" class="form-control">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn">Оставить отзыв</button>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Приведите выбор в соответствие с типом. У Вас

```
STATUS_FEEDBACK = (
    (1, 'Очень плохо'),
    (2, 'Плохо'),
    (3, 'Терпимо'),
    (4, 'Нормально'),
    (5, 'Отлично'),
)
```

А `mark`

```
mark = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_FEEDBACK, verbose_name='Оценка', max_length=400)
```

Тогда нужно `IntegerField` использовать.